# Moving Annual Total with DAX Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to calculate MAT (Moving Annual Total) using DAX, but can't realize exactly what I want.
I have the data as below.

[image]

---

What I'm trying to is calculate the total of treatment for each 12 month, like "Jan 21 - Dec 21" which has 'date' from 2020/1/1 to 2020/12/1. i.e. 'A' appears 4 times in that period, so the result will be like below.

[image]

Then I'd like to continue this for each latest 12 months, and finally visualize it like below.
[image]

---

I've read that I should use CALCULATE and DATESPERIOD in DAX, can't calculate exactly though. The following code is the one I tried and failed.

```
Moving Annual Total = CALCULATE(
COUNTA('2017-2022Q1'[idnum]),
DATESINPERIOD('2017-2022Q1'[mat].[Date], LASTDATE('2017-2022Q1'[mat].[Date]), 12, MONTH))
```

Could someone kindly give me an advise to realize this?
Thanks.

*This is the sample file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gDNeBe5KiKBqx3cZ7G0SMiSQ23w96NF4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please add your sample and expected output as tabular format here instead of attaching image.

Comment: @mkRabbani I added the link of file, I hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your dax measure, I recommend you first to create a date table and create a one-to-many relationship with the fact table(your table: '2017-2022Q1') ; then filter the date table in your calculate measure, not the fact table('2017-2022Q1') directly  as you did here. You should follow the best practice.

```
        For Example: How to create a date table using dax:
        Date =
        VAR MinYear = YEAR ( MIN ( '2017-2022Q1'[date] ) )
        VAR MaxYear = YEAR ( MAX ( '2017-2022Q1'[date] ) )
        RETURN
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            FILTER (
                CALENDARAUTO( ),
                AND ( YEAR ( [Date] ) >= MinYear, YEAR ( [Date] ) <= MaxYear )
            ),
            "Calendar Year", "CY " & YEAR ( [Date] ),
            "Month Name", FORMAT ( [Date], "mmmm" ),
            "Month Number", MONTH ( [Date] )
        )
```

Your final code could be like this:

```
        Moving Annual Total = CALCULATE(
        COUNTA('2017-2022Q1'[idnum]),
        DATESINPERIOD('Date'[Date], LASTDATE('Date'[Date]), -12, MONTH)
        
        )
```

if you define the start date using the lastdate() function, then It returns the last date in your filter context. you should also specify the interval as (-12) month to extract all dates within 1 year period.

Hope It helps.

Comment: Hi Ozan, thanks for your help!
I tried your code, but DAX editor says that "The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value." with date table code.
I'm trying to find the block where it needs the correction, I can't detect exactly though.
Do you have any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Nick Mochizuki Please check your [date]column references are correct (case-sensitive) while writing date table code.  Below is the name of the date column in your fact table. It starts with a lowercase "d".   VAR MinYear = YEAR ( MIN ( '2017-2022Q1'[date] ) )
VAR MaxYear = YEAR ( MAX ( '2017-2022Q1'[date] ) ).                                     After RETURN keyword, CALENDER AUTO() scans the data model for date columns, and create a column named [Date] with uppercase"D", then refer to it during the rest of code until it finishes defining the rest of the columns.

Comment: Hi @Ozan Sen Finally I could realize my goal with your suggestion, thank you very much!

Comment: Hello @NickMochizuki You are welcome! I am pleased to hear that you solved your problem. I wish you good luck.